# Install Ephem on windows through the conda commad prompt

Tags: conda

I have been trying to install Ephem and other packages and dependancies on windows through the the conda command prompt using the code bellow but keep getting the error i have outlined bellow

```
    conda install -c anaconda ephem
```

This is the error I am getting at the end:

```
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: done

 ## Package Plan ##

    environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

    added / updated specs:
     - ephem


    The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ephem              anaconda/win-64::ephem-3.7.7.1-py38he774522_0


    Proceed ([y]/n)? y

    Preparing transaction: done
    Verifying transaction: failed

    EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
    environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

Comment: The error clearly says permission error. May be you are using guest account instead of admin.